# web-part permission

Tags: permissions, list-view, audience-targeting, custom-list

I'm using SharePoint 2007, Custom list.

I have created 3 different view on one list, 
and a custom permission.

in the home page each list-view appear in different wep-part.
In each web-part I defined the advanced target audiences from Distribution/Security Sharepoint groups. (in order that each group will see only one web-part).

is it possible to define for each group a permission level (the custom permission level)?
(in order to limit the group ability on the web-part)
P.S.
is it possible to do it without using sharpoint designer?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common misconception to think that target audience has to do with permissions. Target audiences are ment to push out information to certain audiences, but there are no security involved.

Target audience can be used to determine conditional rendering of OOB webparts, rendering of list items in list view webparts (if audience is enabled on list items), personalization links and more.

The best performing way to use them, is to create target audience rules and compile them. These rules look either on security group membership or user profile property values.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906649.aspx)

Comment: maby I do not informative myself properly, I need to use the target audience with permission and I do not know how to do it. thanks! liron.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the group ability"?